# The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: file, delphi, path

The file is inside the directory where the software is. I am trying to add the text file to the memo box.

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  dir : string;
begin
  Form4.Caption:='Abateri instrumente';
  dir := GetCurrentDir;
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(dir+'\abateri.txt');
end;
```

Comment: Use e.g. `Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'abateri.txt');`.

Comment: I get the exact same error :  "Exception EFopenerrro" "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: There is no `EFopenerrro` exception. Be specific if you want to get help.

Comment: Sorry I misstyped 'EfOpenError' here's a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/ca0suo1.png

Comment: Please, double-check that the file really is in the directory '...\release', and not for ex. in '...\debug'

Comment: Yes I double-checked it , you can check the screenshot for example , moved the file even to C:\test directory to test it , and run as administrator http://i.imgur.com/fgTtGc7.png

Comment: Try LoadFromFile(dir+'\abateri.txt.txt').  In your screenshot the extension for the Project file is hidden, meaning you have the option enabled to hide known file extension, yet the one for the text file shows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your specific situation, you should load the file with the code

```
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(dir+'\abateri.txt.txt');
```

This is because in the below screenshot that you provided, the extension of the Project3 file is hidden, which loads to the conclusion that the option to hide known file extensions is enabled. Yet the one for the abateri.txt file is shown, which can only lead to the often seen double extension mistake.

[image: Supplied screenshot of the error]

Either rename your file and remove the redundant part (the first .txt, which is preferred) or use the double extension in your code.
I would also suggest disabling that option in Windows Explorer:
<kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Folder Options</kbd> > <kbd>View</kbd> > Uncheck the "Hide extensions of known file types"

In addition to the above, you should always build up paths with the `TPath.Combine` function call to ensure that they are correct.
You can see the documentation of it [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine)

Comment: No, you should stop using `GetCurrentDir` function to get the application directory (you can break it simply by calling `SetCurrentDirectory`). But good catch with that extension typo!

Comment: Excellent conclusion. I also fully support your suggestion regarding unhiding extensions of known file types

Comment: @TLama, I fully agree there. In today's age one should never use the application directory, too many UAC issues. One should rather use the `AppData` folder to write/read self maintained files

Comment: Definitely! But my point was more about that `GetCurrentDir` is not reliable for this purpose.

Comment: Nice one , I literally forgot I have the file extensions hidden since I just installed a new harddrive , thanks,now I finally finished my first software :D

Comment: @BerndLinde Great job in spotting this. I also agree with your suggestion to disable the hiding of known file extensions. In fact I strongly recommend this to everyone. Why? I have seen viruses which makes bunch of executable files which are named the same as subdirectories that are present in the directory into which such file is copied. Also this files have same icons that are used by explorer for folders. So without file extensions shown you can't know which is folder and which is executable file. This is used so that user infects his computer again if it was cleaned already.

Answer (score 2):

> The file is inside the directory where the software is.

In that case, looking in the working directory is the wrong approach. There's no reason why the working directory should be directory where your executable resides. You need to use:

```
Dir := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)); // the directory where the executable resides
TPath.Combine(Dir, FileName); // TPath is from the System.IOUtils unit
```

Of course, your other problem is that you got your file name wrong. The file is actually named `abateri.txt.txt`.