# Loading picture from file with filename as a changing variable

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm currently busy with a project, extremely tired and I can't think straight, and I'm having some trouble loading a picture from a file, where the name of the picture is stored in a variable that changes according to what someone selects in  a combobox. The combobox is sorted and the first ItemIndex is the name of the first piece in the table.

Here's the (horrifying and mediocre) code for declaring the file name to a variable:

```
begin
  iTel := 0;

  with dmMusiekstukke do
  begin
    while not (tblMusiekstukke.Eof) AND (iTel <= 4) do
    begin
      tblMusiekstukke.First;
          Inc(iTel) ;
       arrMusic[itel] := tblMusiekstukke['Musicpiece name'] ;
       tblMusiekstukke.Next ;
      end;
  end;

        case cbbMusic.ItemIndex of
        0 : Image := arrMusic[1] ;
        1 : image := arrMusic[2] ;
        2 : Image := arrMusic[3] ;
        3 : Image := arrmusic[4] ;

        end;

       end;
```

The file name of the image is exactly the same as the name of the item in the databases's 'Musicpiece name' field. The array (of string) should be filled with the name of the Musicpiece, which in turn is also the name of the file. Out of the combobox, the person selects the music piece they want  and the picture for that specific music piece is displayed.

Code I have for loading the file :

```
procedure TfrmSheets.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin

imgSheet.Picture.LoadFromFile(  '''' +  frmMusic.Image + '.png');
end;

end.
```

As you can see I'm really not sure how to do it. All the pictures are in .png format. Thank you very much.

Comment: `imgSheet.Picture.LoadFromFile(frmMusic.Image + '.png');`

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. Thank you for commenting, though.

Comment: *I tried, it doesn't work* is doesn't make sense. Based on the code you've posted, it works, so either a) you're using code other than what you've posted here; b) you've not done what I indicated in my previous comment correctly;  or c) you've not described your problem clearly or accurately.

Comment: Alright I took a break and removed 

    tblMusiekstukke.First ; 

out of the while loop. I kept the '''' as it gives a single apostrophe and added it after '.png'. Now the only the error I get is that the system cannot get the file specified. I checked many times, but the names are the same.

Comment: This could be an error on my side as a person, not on Delphi's as a program, but I tried using 
    imgSheet.Picture.LoadFromFile(frmMusic.Image + '.png');
and it still says it cannot find the file specified, and it is located in the same area as where the project is saved. 

Thank you again for commenting.

Comment: Are your files in the same folder as your *project*, or your executable? Your executable is in a folder below your project, in either `\Release` or `\Debug`. The files need to be in that folder.

Comment: The pictures are in the same file as the Application and the project.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Alright I sorted it out. It worked by not adding apostrophes on either sides, that was one of my problems, but the other solution to a problem I found here:   [The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875727/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

I then did this:

```
imgSheet.Picture.LoadFromFile(frmMusic.Image + '.png.png');
```

I also removed

```
tblMusiekstukke.First ;
```

out of the While loop, as it was constantly placing the marker of the table to first item. It now works perfectly.

Comment: Why did you add two extensions to the same file?

Answer (score 0):

be careful. if `frmMusic.Image` contains only the file name, then the picture file must reside in the `\you_project\Win32\Debug`

Can you check, what contains `frmMusic.Image`

Try put this value to `Label`

Comment: Thank you for our effort and comment, but I finally managed to get it right, Thank you!